SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data on React with Vite app
I'm a beginner in the MERN stack. Just started a project and I'm trying to fetch data from my express server to my react server. I used vite to start up the react local server.
However, this is the error message I keep getting in the console, and I'm unable to fetch the data from the backend server
--Backend (index.js)--
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;


app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.json("Running on MERN Deploy Practice");
    console.log("Active now");
});

app.get("/message", (req, res) => {
    res.json({
        "items": ["user1", "user2", "user3"]
    });
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is Running at ${PORT}`);
});

--Frontend (App.jsx)--
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState([  ]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/message")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => setMessage(data));
  }, []);

  ;

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello User</h1>
      {(typeof message.items === 'undefined') ? (
        <p>Loading...</p>
      ) : (
        message.items.map((item, i) => (
        <p key={i}>{item}</p>
      ))
      )}
      <h1>{message}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App

Here's the file paths

I've tried using the JSON.parse() and JSON.stringify() for the data but still not working.

Perhaps you forgot to include the error message?
